# Call a stored procedure from MVC with LINQ without specifying class structure (because its a pivot with dtynamic columns)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to call a stored procedure with a dynamic result set (no of columns) without knowing the exact class model and having to define it up front. Just want to get a dynamic list then loop the rows?

As far as I know I cannot find any examples and not sure this is even possible but would be neat if I could do this...

```
    var query = _db.Database.SqlQuery<????>("EXEC [dbo].[PivotOnMeterReadView]");
    var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749429/anonymous-type-result-from-sql-query-execution-entity-framework

Comment: thanks, i'm struggling as to where to put the code exactly,controller helper class? With it being public static

Comment: A helper class would be sufficient. Or an extension method. Or on your app context. I've worked on projects that grouped these type of methods into ___Repository classes or whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible to execute a Stored Procedure via LINQ. You'll have to use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`. Below is a code snippet which I have used for successful execution of a SP. Hope I could help :)

```
private readonly string sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString); //sqlConnectionString is the database connection.
sqlconn.Open();
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertUsers", sqlconn)) // "InsertUsers" is the name of SP.
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = User; //Here I am passing the "User" variable as an argument to the "@User" paramter
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
sqlconn.Close();
```