# SQLQuery TypeConverter

Tags: typeconverter

In a .Net C# project I'm attempting to apply a TypeConverter to the results returned by a Database.SQLQuery operation. I was under the impression that the class used as the generic param in SQLQuery would activate the TypeConverter that is applied to the class (via a TypeConverter class attribute). It does not work and I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing or if it is possible.

Peter

Comment: As a second note - and what got me here is -- is there anyway to override the mapping performed by SQLQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - well I was trying to push the limits here. Ideally the request I made is not really valid as a supplied type is provided when calling SQLQuery. My issue dealt with a legacy system where multiple DB operations retuned the same result set. There was though a discrepancy between the returned results within the field types. I found a StackOverflow discussion that showed a different strategy to handle my situation:

[Anonymous type result from sql query execution entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749429/anonymous-type-result-from-sql-query-execution-entity-framework)

In the end I used the concept described in this post and extended the database class with an extension that performed queries using a SQL DataReader. In the end it was practically performing an older ADO style retrieval - but gave me the option to validate the return results and make sure they mapped properly to the target class property types.

Peter