# Get MULTIPLE random records using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, random

I have checked [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781893/ef-code-first-how-to-get-random-rows) and other articles on Stack Overflow. I prefer the `Skip` method. However, they are all for single record. Now assume I want to take 20 random records from a table, how can I do that?

I am trying two possibilities:

1. Generate an array of indexes and use Skip for each. This, however, results in 20 queries (and each is ordered by Id too).
2. Fetch the list of all Ids and pick randomly into an array and perform a 2nd query for detailed info all selected Ids.
3. Or just use `OrderBy` as the other post suggested. I think this can be bad because the entire table is ordered?

Please tell me if there is any better solution.

Comment: the answer link you shared in question, it has `take(5)` so can't you use that as `take(20)`, or I didn't get your exact requirement?

Comment: If I use `Take(5)`, it would take 5 consecutive records, not random.

Comment: wouldn't they already be randomized when you do `OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid())`?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi As my 3rd point, I think `OrderBy` will mess up the whole table, so I think using `Skip` would be better. When using `Skip` I only need to use `OrderBy` on Id instead. (please check the 2nd answer, not the marked answer)

Comment: can you use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi Yes, as the answer of this question you see below, I can use pure SQL approach if I cannot find anything else, but I prefer using EF if possible (maybe using [EF Database scalar function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#modeling)).

Comment: I know its writing pure SQL at the bottom line but something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35184536/3621001) can be used too.

Comment: You can make more complicated form of randomness by sorting elements by  order by id % cast(rand() * 1000 as decimal)  clause for example and take top(20) of them.

Comment: can you generate a random number with in range of your table's ids and then use `Find or Single`?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi sadly the ids are not continuous and would not work. Currently I am using what you are suggesting (my 2nd point).

Comment: right. I believe a stored procedure would be optimal in your case then.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use a Stored Proc to do this for you?

So your StoredProcs job is to return 20 records to the caller (I guess this is some Online Exam :D)

on the sql side you can use [SQL Rand()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_rand.asp) to generate random numbers for all rows in your Table. Then Order them by Asc/Desc values of this Random column and Pick top 20.

Comment: Yeah I think this would be the best way. Though I am a C# developer and not really good at writing SQL Server Stored Procedure, will try this one as last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Ordering the table by randomized guid will not leave any effects on the table. The Linq solution achieves what you want to do.

```
private IEnumerable<MyClass> GetRandomItems(int n)
{
    return _dbContext.MyClass.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(n);
}
```

Comment: This I do not know. Are you sure, is there any stat/test for this for a huge table?

Comment: Aha, now I see your point. You are right, it will have negative impact on performance if used on a big table. You seem to already have got to the conclusion of using a stored procedure, and I agree that it would be the best approach (followed by the 20-query version).