# Raw Sql query not working Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Entity Framework:

```
readonly learning_dbEntities learning_db = new learning_dbEntities();

var userRemindersCheck1 = learning_db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select * from UserRemainderEntities");
```

(or)

```
var userRemindersCheck1 = learning_db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select * from UserRemainderEntities").ToList();
```

Both are not working!

It showing no error but data is not displaying. Please provide if you find any solution.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `string` here, it should be a class.

Comment: If possible, provide some syntax or reference links, i will understand better. Thank you responding!

Comment: I used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35184536/6499680, please check once!

Comment: Well you can't just apply random Stack Overflow answers to your code without understanding them.

Comment: If Possible, Please provide some tutorial links so that i will refer and learn Raw Sql syntax better.

Comment: Ok working without string After i refer this:https://medium.com/@9749866865s/how-to-execute-raw-sql-query-by-using-dbcontext-e7928a0b179