# Mapping dynamic type to Property and values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to execute a stored procedure in Entity Framework and for that, I am using this code:

```
public dynamic ExecSp(SqlParameter[] Para, string SpName)
{
    try
    {
        var _data = Context.SqlQuery<dynamic>("exec "+ SpName + " "+ string.Join(",", Para.Select(m=>m.ParameterName)), Para);
        return _data 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

In my code the stored procedure name and parameters are dynamic. When I execute the stored procedure an `{object}` is returned.
I want to map the `{object}` value to property and value so I can easily use the result.

Comment: Have you want to bind the results for certain model/viewmodel class? You can change `dynamic` type parameter in `Context.SqlQuery<dynamic>` to a designated class name instead converting `object`.

Comment: In my case store procedure and parameters  name are come from database table and i can not fix the return type for that. how i can create class for that and  for that i must use `dynamic` type

Comment: Can you include the stored procedure code? If it's using `SELECT` & returns set of entity class property members defined in EF you can use an entity class name instead of `dynamic`. And what kind of relation with MVC in this issue?

Comment: No i can't include  stored procedure in code.

Comment: This will be helpful to you @Jay https://stackoverflow.com/q/26749429/1660178 it is similar question

Comment: EF will ignore properties not returned by the stored procedure when mapping to a class type. In other words, there doesn't have to be a direct 1-1 correlation between the class properties and the SP return. Therefore, you can simply create a class that has a superset of all the properties that could be potentially returned from the SP and use that.

Comment: i will find my solution using @sangramparmar Link.