# Dynamically Selecting Data from Table in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller, dynamic

I know this question might have been asked before but I have not found a single answer yet.

Basically I am using entity framework and I am in need of selecting data from a database without knowing the name of the table, as this will be generic.

Now if I do not know the table name, I do not know the type too as I have tried using context.Database.SQLQuery or context.Database.ExecuteSQLStatement but these all require the type of the object it should be expecting.

All I am receiving as parameters are the name of the table and the row ID.

Could anybody give me further advice?

Thanks.

#

Edit:

I have just been notified that the only property I would need from this table is the Name field...

Comment: You have no idea what the structure of the returned data would be?

Comment: Nope, thats why I'm going abit crazy. Haha

Comment: The query I am trying to generate in pseudo code is as follows:

context.database.sqlquery("Select * from " +tableName+ " Where Id=" +id);

Comment: Looks messy but this looks like a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749429/anonymous-type-result-from-sql-query-execution-entity-framework

Comment: The prefer solution that should be choose is ADO.Net and get result in DataTable.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the "Id" field will always be called `Id` and that the "Name" field will always be called `Name`?