# Mixing raw SQL with IQueryable for dynamic filter

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6, system.linq.dynamic

In entity framework 6 is it possible to mix raw SQL generated dynamically with IQueryable like this:

```
IQueryable<Tree> tree_query = context.Trees.Where(t=>t.Height> 2);
IEnumerable<int> tree_additional_filter = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT Id FROM TREE_VIEW WHERE Width < 1");

IQueryable<Tree> final_query = from tree in tree_query 
                               join filtering_tree in tree_additional_filter on filtering_tree.id equals tree.id
                               select tree;
```

This produces a result as is, but the "tree_additional_filter" is executed in the database in order to construct the final_query. How can I make entity framework construct only one query from this?

I need this to create dynamic filter fields which work together with static ones.

I also tried creating TREE_VIEW entity with only Id column, which I know to always be there.
Used System.Linq.Dynamic to construct "where" clause dynamically on a TREE_VIEW entity which has only Id property, but apparently expressions can't be built if properties do not exist in the Type.

Comment: This code *doesn't* mix queries. Those are two separate queries. The results of the first query are stored in `tree_additional_filter`

Comment: How can I make tree_additional_filter  an Iqueryable to add to the other query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it.

1. Using [Dynamic type generation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28627991/2322986) to create a type (`NewDynamicType`) from fields which I got selecting top 1 from my `TREE_VIEW`. Attached the `NewDynamicType` to the db context via `DbModelBuilder.RegisterEntityType` in `OnModelCreating`.
2. With [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) then I could construct `IQueryable` selecting from `context.Set(NewDynamicType)` any fields the user wants to filter by.
3. Join into `final_query` like in my question.

Now my HTML form gets fields from the database view and in each distibution I can have different filters defined without having to write any c#.

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

> In entity framework 6 is it possible to mix raw SQL generated dynamically with IQueryable like this:

No. Notice that [Database.SqlQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, not an `IQueryable<T>`.  Therefore any additional query expressions will be executed against the query results using LINQ to Objects.

[Query Composition with raw SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#composing-with-linq) queries was introduced in EF Core.

Comment: Can I use reflection somehow to construct the tree_view entity on the fly and attach it to the context so I could trick entity framework into constructing the query? Through dynamic linq or otherwise?