# Can I use DbContext.Database.SqlQuery without a strong element type in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm implementing some generic solution to query IDs from database. All I know, is for example that given a table `A`, it has a column `Id` having an integer type. I don't know if it's `uint32` or `int64`, etc.

I'd like to query the maximum of the ID using `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery`, however, I cannot make it work in a weakly typed manner. So I always have to provide a strong element type, which basically I wouldn't like as it might be `int` or `long`.

If I'm running it like `.SqlQuery<object>`, than I'm getting exception when trying to convert it to for example `long` using `Convert.ToInt64`, saying that `System.Object` is not convertible to that type. Seems like EF is kind of misunderstanding me or so.

Even when the actual underlying type is `Int32`, and I try to query for `long`, I get an exeption stating that I cannot convert `Int32` to `long`, which completely does not make sense to me.

How could I achieve a weakly typed query result which I can just convert to whatever I want?

Comment: Can you cast it to varchar and then parse it in C# maybe?

Comment: `I'd like to query the maximum of the ID` why? Are you trying to use the buggy MAX+1 algorithm to generate new IDs? This risks generating duplicate IDs or worse, associating irrelevant records if the last records are deleted. Why not use EF's built-in identity generation mechanism?

Comment: Btw `SqlQuery` can work with any type, but if you only want to return a single value, you shouldn't be using an ORM. A plain ADO.NET query or eg Dapper could be used to execute that query. Just don't use MAX+1. You can specify alternate ID generation strategies in EF. If you want to know the IDs in advance, a far better solution would be to use a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Just `.SqlQuery<long>(...)` DB types are different from C# types anyway, so the important thing **for a query** is, to have a target type thats big enough to hold the result

Comment: @grek40 Thanks for the comment, yes, this is why I'm suprised how `long` is not working for an `int`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your comments, I am not planning to use is for ID generation of course :) Actually I'm working on kind of a generic database reset functionality for reliable and deterministic integration testing for databases having strictly monotonic IDs. Using EF is just for simplicity as we already have a reference to that. However, I'm thinking about going down to pure ADO, I know it's kind of trivial in that context.

Comment: Maybe you can re-phrase your question with more details as in "This is my table definition, this is my SQL query, I expected `SqlQuery<long>` to work, why does it not work / how to make it work?" Currently, your question doesn't provide such a level of detail, so it's hard to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Entity Framework is designed to map [definite (strong typed) POCO classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd456853(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

> The names of the types and each of the mapped properties must be equivalent.

- You can convert, for example, `long` to `int` with [those techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370104/convert-value-when-mapping). But that also requires you to know column types beforehand.
- You can convert to `dynamic` type with [codes shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749429/anonymous-type-result-from-sql-query-execution-entity-framework). But that is overkill compared with [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples), IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your answer summarizing the conclusion, I'll go with pure ADO API.