# Return Extra Columns in GetRawSQL with Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to return extra dynamic columns in Entity Framework with the `FromSqlRaw`?

The basic concept would be something like this

```cs
var contacts = DbContext.Contacts.FromSqlRaw("Select *, 'Some Dyn Field' as Field1 From Contacts ");
```

How could I get access to `Field1`? I have a much more complex process I am trying to solve but this is a general concept.

Comment: Not directly, though this will probably be along the lines of what you want to do:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749429/anonymous-type-result-from-sql-query-execution-entity-framework  Your example won't work because to return "Contacts", that "Some Dynamic Field" would have to be recognized as part of a Contact entity.

Answer (score 0):

The fields of query  DbContext.Contacts.FromSqlRaw("Select *, 'Some Dyn Field' as Field1 From Contacts ") should contain the same fields  as Contact class of DbContext of your EF otherwise you will have a runtime error. If you wont to have some extra fields you to create a new class - MyExtraField class and add this class to context of EF

```
public virtual DbSet<MyExtraField> MyExtraFields { get; set; }

.............

  modelBuilder.Entity<MyExtraField>(e =>
            {
                e.HasNoKey();
            });
.....
```

If it doesn't fit your requirements you can try to use the good old ADO.NET.

Comment: Yeah these are dynamic and defined at run time so you really can't have a class.